# Can not use limit for select data from database

Tags: php, mysql

I use PHP MySQL select data like this with no error.

```
$sql = "SELECT pd_id, pd_name, pd_price, pd_qty 
        FROM tbl_product ORDER BY pd_id DESC";
```

I want to select only 6 row. So, I edit code like this.

```
$sql = "SELECT pd_id, pd_name, pd_price, pd_qty 
        FROM tbl_product ORDER BY pd_id DESC LIMIT 6";
```

Then , It show error like this.

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'LIMIT 0, 6' at line 2
```

How to select data 6 row from MySQL

Comment: Other than that your query could not produce that error message, there's nothing wrong here

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
$sql = "SELECT pd_id, pd_name, pd_price, pd_qty 
        FROM tbl_product ORDER BY pd_id DESC LIMIT 0, 6 ";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT TYPE FROM stuff ORDER BY STUFF_ID DESC LIMIT 6
```

Replace your query by columns used above